# How to define a default page to load in web.xml for a specific role?

Tags: jsp, deployment, web.xml, descriptor

My question is, when i log in my web application as a specific role (e.g. admin) on a login page, how do I define in deployment descriptor to which file would this role be redirected after successful login.

My web.xml code:

```
<display-name>Fitnes</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/Javno/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WRCollection1</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Zasebno/Trener/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>trener</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Javno/Prijava.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/Javno/PrijavaError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>trener</role-name>
</security-role>
```

After login, not all roles would be redirected to index.jsp, but different files.
Let's say when i log in as "trener", I would like to be redirected to "Trener.jsp"..

For example:

```
<web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WRCollection1</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Zasebno/Trener/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <welcome-file>/Zasebno/Trener/Trener.jsp</welcome-file>
    </web-resource-collection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The Servlet specification does not support the feature you describe. You'd have to code this yourself e.g. with a welcome page that forwards to the correct page based on role.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to read an article over Filters. These Filters in java servlet-programming are used for following purposes:

- to intercept the requests from client before they access the back end
- and to manipulate the response from server to client.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html